# Trouble wiring Hibernate, JDBC and SpringSecurity together

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I am working on a simple Spring web app. I'm using Spring Security for user authentication, and Hibernate for persistence. I want Spring Security to use the database (as opposed to basic in-memory authentication).

However, I am getting an exception when running the app.

```
    SEVERE: Servlet /knights threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$fae0dbb8 cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
```

I have no idea what could be causing this. Could this be an issue with Hibernate-generated proxies? The trouble is, since I'm new to Spring and I'm following various online tutorials, my configuration is a mix of XML and Java configuration files. My Spring Security and DataSource are configured in Java, and Hibernate is configured using XML.

Here's the full stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.handlerExceptionResolver()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6412755f cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.handlerExceptionResolver()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6412755f cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6412755f cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$fe413563.mvcContentNegotiationManager(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:632)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.handlerExceptionResolver(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:596)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$fe413563.CGLIB$handlerExceptionResolver$14(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$fe413563$$FastClassByCGLIB$$71eb2090.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:286)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$fe413563.handlerExceptionResolver(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 31 more
```

### `servlet-context.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Expose the resources folder -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <!-- Map simple view name such as "test" into /WEB-INF/test.jsp -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

### `AppConfig.java`:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.siegedog.browsergame")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

### `PersistenceConfig.java`:

package com.siegedog.browsergame.config;

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.siegedog.browsergame" })
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/knights");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("");
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean fb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        fb.setPackagesToScan("com.siegedog.browsergame");
        fb.setDataSource(dataSource());
        fb.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return fb;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties hibernateProperties() {
        return new Properties() {
            {
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
                setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

### `SecurityConfig.java`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select name, password_hash from users where name = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select name, role from users where name = ?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/dashboard").hasRole("USER")
        .anyRequest().anonymous()
        .and()
            // Generate a form login if none is explicitly provided
            .formLogin()//.failureUrl("/login?error")
            //.usernameParameter("name").passwordParameter("password_hash")
        .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
        .and()
            .csrf();

    }
}
```

And, finally my DAO (pretty straightforward).

### `PizzaDAO.java`:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
public class PizzaDAO {
    @Autowired private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /**
     * @Transactional annotation below will trigger Spring Hibernate
     * transaction manager to automatically create a hibernate session. 
     * See src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml
     */
    @Transactional
    public List<Pizza> findAll() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Pizza> pizzas = session.createQuery("from Pizza").list();
        return pizzas;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save(Pizza pizza) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(pizza);
    }
}
```

## Edit:

I ended up removing all the XML configuration and replacing it with full-Java configs.
My final config consists of `AppConfig.java`, `SpringMvcInitializer.java`, `SpringSecurityInitializer.java` and `WebSecurityConfig.java`. Here's my final, working config, in case anyone is interested:

### AppConfig.java

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
@ComponentScan( {"com.siegedog.knights"} )
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/knights");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("");
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations(
                "classpath:/assets/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean fb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        fb.setPackagesToScan("com.siegedog.knights");
        fb.setDataSource(dataSource());
        fb.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return fb;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return txManager;
    }

    Properties hibernateProperties() {
        return new Properties() {
            {
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
                setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

### SpringMvcInitializer.java

```
public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

### SpringSecurityInitializer.java (see comment)

```
/** Required to inject the proper security filter. */
public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

### WebSecurityConfig.java

This code simply sets the proper rout authentication rules. It also uses the dataSource defined in `AppConfig.java` to authenticate users who are registered.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    /**
     * Important: csrf prevention is on by default.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/dashboard").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/forest").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/arena").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/store").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();

        http
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select name, password_hash, enabled from users where name=?")
            // Hash passwords with sha-256
            .passwordEncoder(new ShaPasswordEncoder(256))
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select name, role from users where name=?");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to add `<context:annotation-config/>` to your `servlet-context.xml` in order to tell Spring to look for your @Configuration annotation.

Comment: I managed to solve my initial issue. I was accidentally mixing up hibernate3 and hibernate4 classes. I've updated the question with the latest issue I'm facing - Hibernate weirdness.

Comment: Somewhere you are trying to bind a factory class into an actual implementation class. Wherever you are trying to set `ContentNegotiationManager` to the ` ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean` call `newInstance()` or some similar method

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated the question with the fixed DAO code, and a full stack trace. The problem is I'm not actually using `ContentNegotiationManager` myself directly. It's being used by something else, and since the exception is thrown in the annotation processing phase, I can't find out more about it, apart from that it has something to do with `handlerExceptionResolver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you have quite some duplication (why are you mixing xml and java config?).

- `<mvc:annotation-driven />` is also `@EnableWebMvc`
- `<tx:annotation-driven />` is `@EnableTransactionManagement`.
- `<context:component-scan />` is `@ComponentScan`

You are injecting the wrong beans instead of a `LocalSessionFactoryBean` inject the `SessionFactory` bean, as that is the whole purpose of a `FactoryBean`.

```
public class PizzaDAO {
@Autowired private LocalSessionFactoryBean mySessionFactory;
```

Should be

```
public class PizzaDAO {
@Autowired private SessionFactory mySessionFactory;
```

And you calling code should remove the `getObject()` as you now have a plain `SessionFactory`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've updated my code with your suggestion but I'm still getting that exception. I've also posted a full stack trace, since it might help. I'm mixing up XML and Java because I've just started working with Spring and I'm relying on various guides that use either XML or Java configs.

Comment: The problem, as I see it, lies in the fact that you have a `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and `@EnableWebMvc`. Especially combined with the duplicate component-scan. Can you add your web.xml as well.